# Why BigText plugin only works with static html?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, responsive-design

I'm using [**BigText**](https://github.com/zachleat/BigText) plugin, and I have a little issue. I hope to be clear:

The text of the divs which are seted *on the air* does not fit until the window is resized...

[**This fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/DxcQy/21/) speaks for itself.

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // doesn't works
    $(".span4").bigtext({
        childSelector: '> #fae'
    });

    $("#fae").text("abc");

    //works
    $(".span4:first").bigtext({
        childSelector: '> #wer'
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">
             <div id="wer">abc</div>
        </div>
        <div id="caca" class="span4">
             <div id="fae"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#fae, #wer {
    margin: 10px;
    margin-top: 90px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    font-weight: 800;
    color: #282B36;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}
.span4 {
    background: red;
    height: 500px;
}
```

Any tip or advice will be appreciated. And if you need more info, let me know and I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it works with **current** text, whenever you **changed** the text, you must **reinitialize** the plugin again:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#fae").text("abc");

    $(".span4").bigtext({
        childSelector: '> #fae'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want this:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DxcQy/22/)

```
$("#fae").text("abc");

$(".span4").bigtext({
    childSelector: '> #wer,> #fae'
});
```